# 2.8 How to lasso select in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode

little help needed here if you don't mind?
So, in 2.79 I was very used to lasso selecting in edit mode - select, move, select, move etc.

But in 2.8 we now have a 'select' button and a 'move' button and I really haven't found a way to do both things at once in the seamless way I was able to in 2.79?

Do I really have to go all the way up to the top left corner of the screen and PRESS the select button, then go all the way back to the model (which is where I'd rather stay) to select it, then go all the way back to the top left corner of the screen again and PRESS the move button, then go all the....you get the idea?

In 2.79 I would hold ALT to drag a lasso around a bunch of verts then be straight back to moving those verts around, but in 2.8 I'm trecking all over the screen?

I know that personal work flows are very different and always hard to explain, but is anyone else feeling that the flow here isn't quite as fluid as in 2.79?

Cheers

Wayne

Comment: *"is anyone else feeling that the flow here isn't quite as fluid as in 2.79?"* Yes, it's called "Beta" and it is not finished yet

Comment: Yeah, but I think that the ui methods that they have put in place are intentional (ie not bugs) unless they get some push back from users?

Comment: If anyone come seeking the REAL answer, here it is: by default in edit mode, blender leave you at box selection mode where you CAN NOT perform lasso select. You need to click and hold the select BUTTON from T menu, and in the drop down menu CLICK on the TWEAK button. Now you should be good to go.

Comment: Yeah, I think things have changed subtilely backwards and forwards over recent months and it now seems that you can get it to behave whichever way you want now if you ask it nicely enough :]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The workflows can in fact be even more seamless in 2.80 if you dedicate some time to learning the new functionality

No, you do not have to drag the mouse to the corner of the screen every time you want to perform some operation.

There is a whole lot of ways to do it now. I am not even sure I will be able to list them all, but:

- You can have move tool active and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + right-click to use lasso select.
- You can have any tool active and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + right-click to use lasso select and transform stuff with regular transform hotkeys <kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>.
- You can select Select Lasso tool from the toolbar and then use it without the move gizmo visible and transform stuff with the regular transform hotkeys <kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>.
- You can switch between tools using keyboard shortcuts: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>-><kbd>2</kbd> for Select Lasso, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>-><kbd>T</kbd>, or <kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd> for transforms.
- You can right-click on the Select Lasso and Move tools on the toolbar and choose Add To Quick Favorites and then access them from Quick favorites menu with <kbd>Q</kbd>.
- You can assign any shortcuts you desire to them.

Comment: Thanks Martin, yeah I think it was simple in the end - I needed to leave Move tool active while having Select tool set to Lasso, then I could stay in Move but use Ctrl to make a Lasso selection without going anywhere!

Comment: As much as I use lasso select, ctrl+right-click is too cumbersome. I love B for box select. Ctrl + left click for box select seems pointless to me.

Comment: To be honest with you I think 'ctrl+right-click is too cumbersome' is not a valid argument or even a statement. I fail to see any logic behind it. It's no different than any other keys we use to interact with software. I think it would be best not to think too much about some buttons you need to press for stuff to happen. It's there. You can press it. It works. If you can't do the job with it, somebody else will. That's all there is to it.

Comment: This problem simply stem from the weird fact that blender by default lock users at box select mode. Lasso select itself never changed, we just have to manually switch to this "tweak" mode to get the full functionality back.

Comment: It's hard to see this as a problem for me. If basic functionality seems locking or limiting in some way, maybe it's time to consider just learning to use it... It's not a problem at all after the 10 minutes you dedicate to learning. There are more options now, not less.